# How to call the values of a C# enum in F#

Tags: c#, enums, f#

I'm writing some F# code and I'd like to use an enum value defined in a c# assembly.
For instance, in the c# assembly I've got this code

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    valueA,
    valueB,
    valueC
}
```

How do I call `MyEnum.valueA` in F#? When I just write that, the compiler shouts:

> Invalid use of a type name and/or object constructor. If necessary use
>   'new' and apply the constructor to its arguments, e.g. 'new
>   Type(args)'. The required signature is:  MyEnum()

Comment: Is there any error identifier? Like `FS00xx` where `x` is a number.

Comment: That's the right way to do it; perhaps you could show more of your F# code in case the error actually lies somewhere else.  For example, is it possible that you've also defined a (non-enum) `MyEnum` type in your F# code?

Comment: If the `enum` is in a class (not necessarily your case) shouldn't it be access by `MyClass.MyEnum` path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... I'm sorry, I've found my problem... 
My C# code was actually:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    @valueA,
    @valueB,
    @valueC
}
```

I know, it's weird, but actually it isn't really "my" c# code...

To call it in F#, I have to write:

```
MyEnum.``valueA``
```